# atom text-editor, Como mostrar erros na linha

Tags: php, atom

O Netbeans por exemplo, indica erro na linha ao não conter um "ponto e virtula", mostrando o motivo ao passar o mouse sobre o número da linha.

Porém o atom não o faz,

Eu sei que tem como, mas não sei instalar isto nele.

Como faz e onde encontro tal addon para isto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome de utilitários para checagem de sintaxe é *linter*.
Um dos linters de php mais populares para o Atom é o [linter-php](https://atom.io/packages/linter-php) e sua instalação pode ser feita com o seguinte comando no seu terminal:

```
apm install linter-php
```

Também há um gif demonstrando a funcionalidade na página do [plugin-base](https://atom.io/packages/linter).

Comment: Como abro o terminal ?

Comment: Windows? É o prompt de comando mesmo.

Comment: Aqui no trabalho é windows, lá em casa me lembro que abre uma janelinha dentro do atom-editor, não seria ela ?

Comment: Parece que está funcionando, digitei no prompt, resultado: none.

Obrigado vou testar no atom agora.

Comment: Simplesmente agora ele colocou os sublinhados em vermelho de texto errado, isso eu não quero, como tiro esta funcionalidade ?

Comment: Acho que consegui, em Settings, desmarquei o sublinhar e reinicie ele valeu

Answer (score 0):

O Linter PHP seria uma boa solução, mas ele foi uma gambiarra temporária. Graças ao [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/), uma comunidade bem ativa e potente adotada pelo Facebook, agora o que era apenas um editor, acabou se transformando em uma verdadeira IDE. A comunidade, já clamava por isso.

Para fazer o seu Atom Editor se transformar em uma IDE oficial, é muito fácil. Vem comigo e siga os passos abaixo:

Instale o pacote [atom-ide-ui](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ide-ui)
Instale o seu pacote de linguagem favorita. Neste caso, o PHP: [ide-php](https://github.com/atom/ide-php/)
Eu escrevi um artigo fazendo um review e um comentário mais bacana da ferramenta do Atom IDE. [Acesse este link para obter mais informações](http://binariux.com.br/seja-bem-vindo-ao-atom-ide/).